# Filling NAs with values of adjacent cells in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This question may sound similar to various other questions on this forum and before flagging it as duplicate, kindly make sure that the duplicate works in my case.

I have a dataframe (**df1**), as follows:

```r
> df1 <- data.frame(c1=c('ER017','ER017','ER017','ER017','ER017','ER018','ER018','ER018','ER018'),c2=c(1,4,3,2,5,3,1,2,4),c3=c(18,NA,20,NA,NA,150,NA,NA,200))
> df1

 c1        c2       c3
-----------------------
ER017       1       18
ER017       4       NA
ER017       3       20
ER017       2       NA
ER017       5       NA
ER018       3      150
ER018       1       NA
ER018       2       NA
ER018       4      200
```

I would like to replace NA in c3 such that the value is from the previous cell based on the values of c1 and c2. For example, for ER017; c2=1, c3=18, so for ER017; c2=2, c3 would be 18 but for ER017; c2=4, c3 would be 20 as the value is changed for ER017 and c2=3, which is the prior cell. Similarly, for ER018, c2=1 and c2=2, c3 should have 150 as for c2=3 corresponds to c3=150.

Below is my desired output:

```
 c1        c2       c3
-----------------------
ER017       1       18
ER017       2       18
ER017       3       20
ER017       4       20
ER017       5       20
ER018       1      150
ER018       2      150
ER018       3      150
ER018       4      200
```

I have tried the following code snippets but the resulting output is not correct.

```
> library(zoo)
> library(dplyr)

> df1 %>% arrange(c1,c2) %>% group_by(c1,c2) %>% mutate(c3 = na.locf0(c3)) %>% ungroup


c1       c2    c3
-------------------
ER017     1    18
ER017     2    18
ER017     3    20
ER017     4    20
ER017     5    20
ER018     1    20
ER018     2    20
ER018     3   150
ER018     4   200
```

```
> df1 %>% arrange(c1, c2) %>% fill(c3) %>% fill(c3, .direction = "up")

c1    c2   c3
--------------
ER017  1   18
ER017  2   18
ER017  3   20
ER017  4   20
ER017  5   20
ER018  1   20
ER018  2   20
ER018  3  150
ER018  4  200
```

None of these solutions work in my case as for ER018, c2=1 and 2, c3 should be 150 but somehow the value 20 is carried forward from ER017 to ER018. Can anybody help in getting my desired output as mentioned above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `.direction = "downup"` in `fill()` to fill missing values first down and then up.

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(c1) %>%
  arrange(c2, .by_group = T) %>%
  fill(c3, .direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#   c1       c2    c3
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 ER017     1    18
# 2 ER017     2    18
# 3 ER017     3    20
# 4 ER017     4    20
# 5 ER017     5    20
# 6 ER018     1   150
# 7 ER018     2   150
# 8 ER018     3   150
# 9 ER018     4   200
```

Comment: When I try the above code, I get an error: `Error in order(c2, .by_group = T) : argument lengths differ`

Comment: It was a problem on my side...loaded extra libraries which created problem with the `arrange() ` function. Solved it by using ` dplyr::arrange(c2, .by_group = T) %>% `

Answer (score 3):

Similar using solution to Darren but using `nafill` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
df1[order(c2), nafill(nafill(c3, type = 'locf'), type = 'nocb'), by = c1]
```

Comment: Using your code, i get the error message: `Error in nafill(nafill(c3, type = "locf"), type = "nocb") : could not find function "nafill"`

Comment: My guess is that you are lacking the `data.table` package, or have an older version of the package. I suggest trying to install the package using `install.packages("data.table")` or `update.packages()` (if it is already installed). Lastly i'm running `R3.6.3` and `R4.0.0` and maybe the function was introduced into the package after a certain version of `R`.

Answer (score 2):

Base R solution:

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df1, df1$c1), function(x){
      x <- x[order(x$c2),]
      x$c3[1] <- ifelse(is.na(x$c3[1]), x$c3[which(!(is.na(x$c3)))[1]], x$c3[1])
      x$c3 <- na.omit(x$c3)[cumsum(!(is.na(x$c3)))]
      return(x)
    }
  )
), row.names = NULL)
```